# Sound does not work in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, sound

Sounds was working until update of ubuntu 16.04. Have done few installations as well. Now sound does not working. Even the sound icon cannot be seen in upper conner. When I check the sound properties it shows as follows.
[Sound Settings screenshort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BShtH.png).

Note : My computer is dualboot with windows 8.1 and sounds in windows working fine. Computer is Asus X555L
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Start by disabling Secure Boot at UEFI. Do the sound works now?

Comment: It is already disabled.